# How to maximize the speed of disk cloning via `dd`?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I want to copy **entire** disk from /dev/sda to /dev/sdb accurately, so I would like to use `dd` command in Linux, but there are two options confused me, `bs` and `sync`.

> dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=4096 conv=notrunc,noerror,sync

- Should I add `sync` option as [wiki.archlinux.org suggested](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_Cloning#Cloning_an_entire_hard_disk)?
- Should I set `bs=16384kB` as the disk cache size rather than the larger number to maximize the speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I add sync option as wiki.archlinux.org suggested?

If you're going to use the `conv=noerror` option, then you had better use the `conv=sync` with it, or you might end up with a useless backup.

Per the Linux man page

```
Each CONV symbol may be: 
...
sync
    pad every input block with NULs to ibs-size; when used with block or unblock, pad with spaces rather than NULs
```

This option that can add padding is necessary when also specifying the `noerror`, or "continue after read errors", option.  The disk controller provides no sector data for the input buffer when a hard (i.e. unrecoverable) read error occurs.  If **dd** terminated on such an error (as it normally would), then the lack of data is not an issue.

However when "continue after read errors" is specified, the lack of data is then an issue.  If the input buffer is not padded to account for the sector(s) that is/are unreadable, then the subsequent data that are written will be offset from the proper sectors that they should be written to.  Or if the subsequent data skipped over the destination sectors corresponding to the errors (or did a *seek* (in **dd** parlance) to its corresponding sector), then the garbage data in those skipped-over sectors would be treated as copies of original data.

If you were using **dd** to copy blocks that had an integral sequence number, then padding might not be necessary to detect or account for missing blocks.  Raw disk sectors cannot be presumed to have any such integral sequence numbering, and require padding to try to preserve the integrity of the copied filesystem.

Note that there are two `sync` options available with **dd**.
One is `conv=sync` and the other is `iflag=sync`.  They have different meanings.

> Should I set bs=16384kB as the disk cache size rather than the larger number to maximize the speed?

What "the larger number" are you referring to?

The `bs`, block size, parameter has nothing to do with the cache size (although I'm not sure of which cache you're referring to.)
16MB is probably overkill, as there may not even be that much DMAable memory available to lock down.  There are some benchmark tests for varying the block size, and the ones I've seen, such as [this one](http://www.mail-archive.com/eug-lug@efn.org/msg12073.html), confirm my suspicion that there is a size of diminishing (or at least no more) return, which seems to be about 512KB.

A classic value for `bs` when copying a HDD used to be the track size in bytes (or num_of_sectors_per_track * 512 bytes).  But since modern HDDs use zoned bit recording and vary the areal density, there is no fixed (or known for that matter) "number of sectors per track". The typical published specification of "63 sectors per track" on modern drives is merely a numerical convenience.

Answer (score 1):

Not that dd won't do the task, but you might consider using dd_rescue if it's available. It 
provides the ability to deal better with any corrupted sectors and it does a better job of providing status information during the copy. The syntax is slightly different:

```
# dd_rescue [options] infile outfile
# using a 1M block size allows dd_rescue to adjust it's reads/writes to the limits of the OS buffer 

dd_rescue -b 1M /dev/sda /dev/sdb

#sample of the status
dd_rescue: (info): Using softbs=1048576, hardbs=4096
dd_rescue: (info): ipos:   1048576000.0k, opos:   1048576000.0k, xferd:   1048576000.0k
               errs:      0, errxfer:         0.0k, succxfer:   1048576.0k
         +curr.rate:  107936kB/s, avg.rate:  107268kB/s, avg.load: 98.6%
         >-----------------------------------------< 100%  ETA:  0:00:00
```

You may find that increasing the speed of the clone a little is less important than being informed as to how long the process is taking.

Be advised that the initial average transfer speeds can be misleading, as the first 50GB or so of a spinning platter drive is up to 30% faster than the rest. It copies from the physically shorter tracks on the inside of the disk and slows down as the tracks get longer. You won't see that for SSD's, of course.

Answer (score 0):

`bs` means that n `b` (bytes) are read and written each time. It stands for **block size**. `bs` does not necessarily affect the **input block size** `ibs` nor the **output block size** `obs`.

`sync` tells the process to wait until all data has been correctly written to disk **before** moving on to the next **block**. This is usually better to ensure data integrity and to avoid data loss in case of a power outage (such as disconnecting the drive just as it has finished writing data), but it is **slower**.

Without `sync` the copying process is overall faster and the device may be done writing sooner than with `sync` enabled, but you may notice that when information has been completely copied, in fact the disk may be still writing information from its cache to the real support. This is often good for hard drives or when you don't plan to disconnect the device as soon as the copy has been done.

Simply put:

- `sync` → wait information to be completely written to real support.
- without `sync` → send info. to device and let it handle the real write.

You can speed up the process (a little) with `sync` option enabled by using a large **block size** `bs` to avoid *repeteadly accessing the disk between small amounts of time* and thus making the overall process slower.

I've always used `dd` without the `sync` option and I've never experienced any issues, just wait for information to be completely written prior to ejecting any device.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please tell me which number for `bs=` is better for IDE HDD? 10000k? 20000k? or it would be better to be a multiple of 512 (sector size)?

Comment: You explanation for `conv=sync` (which is in the question) is incorrect. You're describing `iflag=sync` (which is not in the question).

Comment: @sawdust I read that information about `sync` on a post regarding HDD pseudo-benchmarking using `dd`,  and I've experienced that behaviour using that option. But I may be wrong. Could you please elaborate on the differences between them?

Comment: @KevinDongNaiJia And as for the `bs` I'd suggest using the same size as the drive's cache, but `4M` is a good value, also I'd suggest to explicitly set the `ibs` and `obs` block sizes; as the man page for `dd` states, the `bs` option does not necessarily set the *input block size* nor the *output block size*.

Comment: @arielnmz Do you mean that I should do something like `bs=4M ibs=4M obs=4M`? But according to [Wikipedia::dd::Block Size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)#Block_size), the block size (bs) option will override both ibs and obs. :-)

Comment: @KevinDongNaiJia if you've set both `ibs` and `obs` then you don't have to specify `bs`. That's what the manual page for `dd` said.